# How to create predefined values and use them in TextFields without overriding the original values

Tags: swift, swiftui

Let's assume I have two views: ParentView, ChildView and ParameterModel. The idea is that user can define some parameters and use their values as starting point value in another place of the app.

When I click on the "add parameter" button on the ParentView, a list of parameters will show up and then I can choose one of the parameter and it's value will be put into TextFields in the form.

Then I want to change the parameter value in the TextField and here is my problem. Because of the binding, when I change parameter's value in the ParentView it will also change the original value.

How can I prevent that? Should I make a copy of the parameter and use it's values to fill up the TextFields? Or maybe my whole concept is bad and there is another, proper way to achieve that?

You will find the working example below:

```
struct ParentView: View {
    
    @State private var showParameters: Bool = false
    @State var chosenParameter: Parameter = Parameter(id: UUID(), name: "", notes: "")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Button {
                    showParameters.toggle()
                } label: {
                    Text("Add parameter")
                }
                
                Section(header: Text("Parameters")) {
                    TextField("parameter", text: $chosenParameter.name)
                    TextField("notes", text: $chosenParameter.notes)
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showParameters) {
                ChildView(chosenParameter: $chosenParameter)
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ParentView()
}
```

```
struct ChildView: View {
    
    @Binding var chosenParameter: Parameter
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(Parameter.parameterList) {parameter  in
                    Button {
                        chosenParameter = parameter
                        dismiss()
                    }label: {
                        Text(parameter.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ChildView(chosenParameter: .constant(Parameter.parameterList[2]))
}

class Parameter: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var notes: String
    
    init(id: UUID, name: String, notes: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.notes = notes
    }
    
    static var parameterList: [Parameter] = [
        Parameter(id: UUID(), name: "Parameter 1", notes: "Notes 1"),
        Parameter(id: UUID(), name: "Parameter 2", notes: "Notes 2"),
        Parameter(id: UUID(), name: "Parameter 3", notes: "Notes 3"),
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a struct instead of a class as suggested in another answer is a very good solution but if you for some reason must have a class then you could add a copy method so your original objects remain unchanged

```
func copy() -> Parameter {
    Parameter(id: self.id, name: self.name, notes: self.notes)
}
```

Then in the view do

```
Button {
    chosenParameter = parameter.copy()
    dismiss()
}
```

Comment: I want to persist Parameter using SwiftData so I think class is a must but I'll try to use copy func as you mentioned so thank you for that answer.

Comment: And that worked! Thanks, once again!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no particular reason for Parameter to be a class, just changing it to struct will solve your issue. Classes are reference types, and since you were binding that reference to the parent View any change would be reflected in the underlying parameterList array. This does not happen using structs, which are value types, and are also the recomended way by Apple to represent data, unless there is a specific reason, as I said. For example, if you need to conform to ObservableObject then you would need a class. So, just replacing class with struct will solve your problem:

```
struct Parameter: Identifiable {
    /// The rest is the same
}
```

Let me know if this sounds like a good solution to you!

Comment: I want to persist Parameter using SwiftData so I think class is a must.